# Storing results of multiple commands in a single file

Tags: windows, command-line, scripting, batch-file

I have a batch file with two commands as listed below.

```
  ping google.com > C:\Test\logfile.txt
  ping yahoo.com > C:\Test\logfile.txt
```

When I run it (in Windows XP), only the result for the last command is getting stored in the file.

**Questions**

1. How can we make both the commands to store the results?
2. Can we specify the filename in one place so that all the commands will store the result in that file?

**Reference:**

1. [how to direct output into a txt file in bat script in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617778/how-to-direct-output-into-a-txt-file-in-bat-script-in-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "logfile=C:\Test\logfile.txt"
(
ping google.com 
ping yahoo.com
)>"%logfile%"            
type "%logfile%"
```

Answer (score 5):

When only one `>` is used, the contents of the file is overwritten. However, when you use two, it appends it.

Example:

```
ping google.com >> C:\Test\logfile.txt
ping yahoo.com >> C:\Test\logfile.txt
```

Would store the output of both commands.

Answer (score 3):

Insted of using :-

```
ping google.com > C:\Test\logfile.txt
ping yahoo.com > C:\Test\logfile.txt
```

Use this :-

```
echo ping google.com >> C:\Test\logfile.txt
echo ping yahoo.com >> C:\Test\logfile.txt
```

This will solve your 1st question (both commands results will be stored).